# Что написать в функции, чтобы сортировка была по условию?

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

Пишу приложение на swiftui с использованием Firebase. Сейчас сортировка документов идет по дате публикации. Нужно, чтобы на первом месте показывались документы, которые в базе Firebase содержат не пустой массив upPostPlusDay. Вот код.
Модель для записи данных в базу Post:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct Post: Identifiable, Codable, Equatable, Hashable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var text: String
    var postHead: String
    var postAddress: String
    var imageURL: URL?
    var imageReferenceID: String = ""
    var publishedDate: Date = Date()
    var likedIDs: [String] = []
    var dislikedIDs: [String] = []
    var plusFavorites: [String] = []
    var upPostPlusDay: [Int] = []
    var userName: String
    var userUID: String
    var userProfileURL: URL
    var userBioLink: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case id
        case text
        case postHead
        case postAddress
        case imageURL
        case imageReferenceID
        case publishedDate
        case likedIDs
        case dislikedIDs
        case plusFavorites
        case upPostPlusDay
        case userName
        case userUID
        case userProfileURL
        case userBioLink
    }
}
```

Код вывода пользователю:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct ReusablePostViewContentView: View {
    var basedOnUID: Bool = false
    var uid: String = ""
    @Binding var posts: [Post]
    @State private var isFetching: Bool = true
    @State private var paginationDoc: QueryDocumentSnapshot?
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyVStack {
                if isFetching {
                    ProgressView()
                        .padding(.top, 30)
                } else {
                    if posts.isEmpty {
                        Text("Записи отсутствуют")
                            .font(.caption)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .padding(.top, 30)
                    } else {
                        Posts()
                    }
                }
                

            }
            .padding(15)
        }
        .refreshable {
            guard !basedOnUID else {return}
            isFetching = true
            posts = []
            paginationDoc = nil
            await fetchPosts()
        }
        .task {
            guard posts.isEmpty else {return}
            await fetchPosts()
        }
    }
        @ViewBuilder
    func Posts() -> some View {
        ForEach (posts) { post in
            PostCardViewContentView(postDog: post) { updatedPost in
                if let index = posts.firstIndex(where: { post in
                    post.id == updatedPost.id
                }) {
                    posts[index].likedIDs = updatedPost.likedIDs
                    posts[index].dislikedIDs = updatedPost.dislikedIDs
                }
            } onDelete: {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.25)) {
                    posts.removeAll {post.id == $0.id}
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                if post.id == posts.last?.id && paginationDoc != nil {
                    Task {await fetchPosts()}
                    // print("Получить новые записи")
                }
            }
            
            Divider()
                .padding(.horizontal, -15)

        }
    }
    func fetchPosts() async {
        do {
            var query: Query!
            if let paginationDoc {
                query = Firestore.firestore().collection("Posts")
                    .order(by: "publishedDate", descending: true)
                    .start(afterDocument: paginationDoc)
                    .limit(to: 5)
            } else {
                query = Firestore.firestore().collection("Posts")
                    .order(by: "publishedDate", descending: true)
                    .limit(to: 5)
            }
            
            if basedOnUID {
                query = query.whereField("userUID", isEqualTo: uid)
            }
            
            let docs = try await query.getDocuments()
            let fetchedPosts = docs.documents.compactMap { doc -> Post? in
                try? doc.data(as: Post.self)
            }
            await MainActor.run(body: {
                posts.append(contentsOf: fetchedPosts)
                
                paginationDoc = docs.documents.last
              
                isFetching = false
            })
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.